# Correct way to fetch data via API in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, design-patterns, pagination, fetch-api

I am learning javascript and React and the challenge (on Hackerrank practise) is to fetch data from an API which has multiple pages. There should be as many buttons as the number of pages and on clicking each button, the data from that particular page should show up below like:
[image]

Here is the component that I wrote:

```js
import React from 'react';

const url = "https://jsonmock.hackerrank.com/api/articles?page=";
const default_page = 1;

class Articles extends React.Component {
  state = {
    pageCount: 1,
    body: {},
    currentPage: 1,
    error: null,
    isLoading: false,
    data: []
  };

  componentDidMount(){
    this.setState({isLoading: true});
    fetch(url+default_page)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(body => this.setState({
      pageCount: body.total_pages, 
      data: body.data,
      body: body,
    }))
    .catch(err => this.setState({error: err}));
  }

  pageButtonGenerator(){
    if(this.state.body){
      let pageButtons=[];
      for(var i=1; i<=this.state.pageCount; i++){
        const id = i; //need this to use in event handler, BUT WHY DOES i NOT WORK (the value is always i=this.state.pageCount)
        pageButtons.push(<button data-testid="page-button" key={"page-button-"+i} onClick={(e) => this.buttonClickHandler(id)}>{i}</button>);
      }
      return pageButtons;
    }
    else{
      return <button data-testid="page-button" key="page-button-1">1</button>
    }
  }

  buttonClickHandler = (pageNum) => {
    // console.log(pageNum);
    this.setState({isLoading: true});
    fetch(url+pageNum)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(body => this.setState({
      pageCount: body.total_pages, 
      data: body.data,
      body: body,
      currentPage: pageNum
    }))
    .catch(err => this.setState({error: err}));
    // this.titlesGenerator();
  }

  titlesGenerator = () => {
    if(this.state.data){
      return this.state.data.map((element,index) => {
        if(element.title){ return <li key={"title-"+index+1} data-testid="result-row">{element.title}</li> }
        else{ return null }
      })
      // console.log(this.state.data);
      
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <div className="pagination">
          {this.pageButtonGenerator()}
        </div>
        <ul className="results">
        {this.titlesGenerator()}
        </ul>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}

export default Articles;
```

Although my code passed the test cases, I am not very confident if I did it the right way. I have my doubts like:

1. Should I be fetching all the pages in one go to avoid multiple network calls or should a call be made every time a page button is clicked?
2. Am I generating buttons the right way (see the `pageButtonGenerator`)?
3. Inside the for-loop in `pageButtonGenerator`, am I calling the onClick handler the right way? I was trying to directly pass the variable "i" but it was always = 6 (the exit value of the loop). I am struggling to understand why the variable i was also 6. I thought the closure would ensure that the value is always correct..
4. How should I go about what to store in state and what should be derived and not stored?

Open to constructive criticism. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

1. You fetch a page per request for the simple reason that it is overkill to fetch all pages, if all the user visits is page 1.
2. &3: Typically you would rather create a widget React component that wraps the paginator in a separate component and pass number of pages to it.
   This widget is merely a list that you style to be a pagination widget.
   So indeed, the logic inside `pageButtonGenerator` is sort of unnecessary.
   4: When dealing with ajax, usually I would have three properties:

   { isFetching, result, error }

`result` is a nested object containing all properties that are a result of the ajax call.
Properties belonging to pagination will be passed to the pagination widget.
Properties that can be derived are usually not stored; if you forget to update them, it results in bugs. Imo, it is better to derive at runtime.

More notes:

- This is 2020, use functional components if you can.
- I don't like it very much to do all state management in React components.
  Check out Redux, and Redux observable if you want cleaner separation of concerns.
  This will also answer many of your questions of what goes where.

Answer (score 1):

I try to explain in easy term:

> Should I be fetching all the pages in one go to avoid multiple network calls or should a call be made every time a page button is clicked?

A: No think as practical scenario if you are making web app and you have 500 pages. Does it make sense to fetch all 500 pages on the go even you cant say user can go each and every page. Good rule of thumb is you get to know about total data available and do `pagination`. For example user click on 5 page. Then fetch 5 page data. Before that when even you are not sure user going to click or not why you adding overhead in user browser. Hope that answer this question.

> Am I generating buttons the right way (see the pageButtonGenerator)?

A: Yes. Better way to learn about pagination. But you are handling dynamic button generation right

> Inside the for-loop in pageButtonGenerator, am I calling the onClick handler the right way? I was trying to directly pass the variable "i" but it was always = 6 (the exit value of the loop). I am struggling to understand why the variable i was also 6. I thought the closure would ensure that the value is always correct..

A: Yes you are right its closure issue. The reason why its happening because you are using

```
for(var i=1; i<=this.state.pageCount; i++){
//var keyword
```

`var` in javascript is function scope it means var is sitting in function scope so when  `buttonClickHandler` get the value it after the loop already run i.e its already set 5 time when loop closes its 6 one. That's why its sending 6 as id.
Easiest solution is use : `let` `for(let i=1; i<=this.state.pageCount; i++){`

> How should I go about what to store in state and what should be derived and not stored?

Generally good rule of thumb is `error`,`loading` and `data`  state. Based on its combination you can show result. Critical data like pagecount, current data should be stored in your state without that you will not get what will be next and previous state